# AutoComplete-Esque Tree

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, tree

I've written a tree data structure that takes in input from the user, and stores the each letter based on the previous letter in the text. I'm not sure what this is called, but the closest I can find is an auto complete type of tree, where someone would traverse this tree to find the next letter with the highest frequency, then build off that to form a word to suggest.

I'm mainly looking for performace/algorithm critiques and suggestions, specifically in the `add_node` function. This is where I had the most problems while writing this, and the excess amount of comments are me "thinking aloud" to myself while working through the problem.

```py
"""
Letter Frequency Tree. This populates a tree based on the users input, keeping track of words entered and the 
frequency of each letter the user inputs.

@author Ben Antonellis
"""

import string

class Node:
    
    def __init__(self, letter: str) -> None:
        self.letter = letter
        self.count = 0
        self.nodes = []

    def add_node(self, node: object) -> None:
        # Check if the string is currently empty:
        if node.letter == "":
            # Now we return since we're all out of letters
            return
        # Determine if letter is already a child node
        next_node = self.__has_letter_node(node.letter[0])
        # If there is no child node for that letter
        if next_node == None:
            # We need to create a new node with the new letter
            new_node = Node(node.letter[0])
            # Because there is no child, we increment the count by 1
            new_node.count += 1
            # Now we add the node to the nodes list
            self.nodes.append(new_node)
            # Now we need to work with the rest of the letters on the new node, skipping the front letter
            new_node.add_node(Node(node.letter[1:]))
        # If there is a child node present
        else:
            # We need to add the count to that letter
            next_node.count += 1
            # Now we add the next letters to the current node
            next_node.add_node(Node(node.letter[1:]))

    def __has_letter_node(self, letter: str) -> object | None:
        for node in self.nodes:
            if node.letter == letter:
                return node
        return None
    
    def has_nodes(self) -> bool:
        return self.nodes != []

    def __str__(self, level=0) -> str:
        # Martijn Pieters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20242504/8968906
        ret = "\t" * level + repr(self.letter) + str(self.count) + "\n"
        for child in self.nodes:
            ret += child.__str__(level + 1)
        return ret

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.__str__()


class AutoCompleteTree:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.roots = [ Node(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase ]

    def get_root_letter_node(self, letter: str) -> Node:
        for node in self.roots:
            if node.letter == letter:
                return node
    
    def print_tree(self) -> None:
        for root in self.roots:
            if root.has_nodes():
                print(root)
    
    def store_input(self, text: str) -> None:
        node = self.get_root_letter_node(text[0])
        node.count += 1
        node.add_node(Node(text[1:]))

def main():
    tree = AutoCompleteTree()
    while True:
        text = input(">>> ")
        tree.store_input(text)
        tree.print_tree()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Previously you've mentioned the difference between `is None` and `== None` why have you chosen the latter? Why have you chosen `self.nodes` to be a `list` not a `dict`? Why have you got a ton of comments in `add_node` but none in the other methods?

Comment: @Peilonrayz The comments in `add_node` are essentially me thinking aloud, as I had the most trouble with that part (which could definitely be mentioned in the question, now that I think of it). `self.nodes` is a list because it's the first collection I thought of to store child nodes. I forgot about using `is None` so that's definitely something I can fix on my end.

Comment: Rely on "$ [ruff](https://pypi.org/project/ruff) ."
to remind you about `is None` and similar details.

Comment: This data structure is called a "trie" or "prefix tree", if you want to read more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in all I think your implementation is well done. Clearly, if I didn't have at least a *few* comments, I wouldn't be taking the trouble to post an answer. Admittedly some (hopefully not all) of my comments could be considered "nitpicking."

**Improved Data Structures**

The `Node.nodes` attribute is a `list` when, as I believe you now know, making it a `dict` that maps a letter to a `Node` instance would permit faster searching. Likewise for the `AutoCompleteTree.roots` attribute which should also be a dictionary that maps a letter to a `Node` instance.

**Type Hints**

If you are going to do use type hints, there might be some room for improvement. Function `__has_letter_node` is defined as follows:

```py
    def __has_letter_node(self, letter: str) -> object | None:
```

I believe ideally you would want to use `-> Node | None`, but `Node` has not been defined yet (also using operator `|` is not supported on my Python 3.8.5). So the changes I had to make for this to run was to predefine an empty class `Node` and then to redefine it. There may be a better, alternate method that I am not aware of:

```py
from typing import Union # Needed for Python < 3.10

# So we can reference Node in class Node:
class Node:
    pass

# Redefinition of Node:
class Node:
    ...

    def has_letter_node(self, letter: str) -> Union[Node, None]:
```

But in fact, if we use the correct data structure for `Node.nodes`, then we don't even really need this function, a call to which can be replaced with the expression `self.nodes.get(letter)`, which will return either the `Node` instance or `None`.

**Don't Do More Work Than Necessary**

`AutoCompleteTree.store_input` calls `node.add_node(Node(text[1:]))` and in method `Node.add_node` we have the recursive calls `new_node = Node(node.letter[0])` and `next_node.add_node(Node(node.letter[1:]))`. In both instances you are first constructing a `Node` instance to be passed to `add_node` but `add_node` is only referencing the string held in `node.letter`. There is not much point in constructing a `Node` when we could simply be passing instead the string that would otherwise be stored in `node.letter`. Also, I would suggest that a better name for the method is `Node.add_nodes` because the method is called in general to add multiple nodes (this is one of the nitpicking recommendations!).

**Remove Tail Recursion**

Method `Node.add_node` uses recursion of a special form, i.e. *tail recursion*. This is where the recursive calls are the final action performed in the function/method before it returns. With such functions iteration can easily replace recursion making for a more efficient implementation.

**Some More Nitpicking Recommendations**

1. Most of the attributes and methods used in these two classes are not to be accessed by client code and as such should have names starting with an underscore ('_') to suggest that these entities are "private."
2. You have taken a standard instance method, `__str__` and added an additional, nonstandard argument, *level*. My preference would be to instead define a new private method `_to_string`:

```py
    def _to_string(self, level=0):
        # Martijn Pieters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20242504/8968906
        the_string = "\t" * level + repr(self.letter) + str(self.count) + "\n"
        for child in self.nodes.values():
            the_string += child._to_string(level + 1)
        return the_string

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self._to_string()
```

Method `__repr__` just delegates to the new method. We don't need to define a `__str__` method since `Node.__repr__` will be called in its absence. Note that I have also replaced variable name `ret` with `the_string`.

3. Method `Node.has_nodes` could be coded as:

```py
    def has_nodes(self) -> bool:
        return True if self.nodes else False
```

This works whether `self.nodes` is a list or dictionary.

4. Your `main` function loops indefinitely. You might want to test and terminate for empty input.

**Suggestions Put Into Code**

If you were to adopt all of the above suggestions, the code would look like the following (it may also assist you if some of my comments above were not as clear as I would have liked):

```py
"""
Letter Frequency Tree. This populates a tree based on the users input, keeping track of words entered and the
frequency of each letter the user inputs.

@author Ben Antonellis
"""

import string

class _Node:

    def __init__(self, letter: str) -> None:
        self._letter = letter
        self._count = 0
        self._nodes = {}

    def add_nodes(self, text: str) -> None:
        current_node = self
        # Check if the string is currently empty:
        for letter in text:
            # Determine if letter is already a child node
            next_node = current_node._nodes.get(letter)
            # If there is no child node for that letter
            if next_node is None:
                # We need to create a new node with the new letter
                new_node = _Node(letter)
                # Because there is no child, we increment the count by 1
                new_node._count += 1
                # Now we add the node to the nodes list
                current_node._nodes[letter] = new_node
                # Now we need to work with the rest of the letters on the new node, skipping the front letter
                current_node = new_node
            # If there is a child node present
            else:
                # We need to add the count to that letter
                next_node._count += 1
                # Now we add the next letters to the current node
                current_node = next_node

    def has_nodes(self) -> bool:
        return True if self._nodes else False

    def _to_string(self, level=0):
        # Martijn Pieters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20242504/8968906
        the_string = "\t" * level + repr(self._letter) + str(self._count) + "\n"
        for child in self._nodes.values():
            the_string += child._to_string(level + 1)
        return the_string

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self._to_string()


class AutoCompleteTree:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._roots = {c: _Node(c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase}

    def _get_root_letter_node(self, letter: str) -> _Node:
        return self._roots[letter]

    def print_tree(self) -> None:
        for root in self._roots.values():
            if root.has_nodes():
                print(root)

    def store_input(self, text: str) -> None:
        node = self._get_root_letter_node(text[0])
        node._count += 1
        node.add_nodes(text[1:])

def main():
    tree = AutoCompleteTree()
    while True:
        text = input(">>> ")
        if not text:
            break
        tree.store_input(text)
        tree.print_tree()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `Node | None` is syntactic sugar for `Union[Node, None]` in type hints. And much more readable. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the info. It first generated an error for me due to class `Node` not having been defined yet. That is why I first defined an empty class `Node` and then redefined the class. Then I got: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'**. Using `Union` resolved that for me (Python 3.8.5).